# Defining custom views in a list's schema.xml file

Tags: custom-list, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have create a custom list definition, with a content type.

In the schema.xml, I'd like to define two views :

- All items (the default one, generated by Visual Studio)
- My items (the same view with a filter based on the user id)

When I deploy my list, the two views are actually created, bu the filter I define for the second one disappeared.

Here is the filter I use :

```
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified"
                  Ascending="FALSE">
        </FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
          <Value Type="Integer">
            <UserID />
          </Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
    </Query>
```

What is missing ? If I use SPD to create the filter after the deployment, it generates exactly this query.

Don't know if it can help, but here is the whole view definition :

```
  <View BaseViewID="1"
        Type="HTML"
        WebPartZoneID="Main"
        DisplayName="My messages"
        DefaultView="TRUE"
        MobileView="True"
        MobileDefaultView="True"
        SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx"
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/announce.png"
        Url="MyMessages.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">mycustomxsl.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements"
                        Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo"
                        Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments">
      </FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
      </FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Modified">
      </FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified"
                  Ascending="FALSE">
        </FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
          <Value Type="Integer">
            <UserID />
          </Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
    </Query>
  </View>
```

[Edit]: I'm a bit confused with the `<View BaseType="1">` attribute. As I want to keep the AllItems view, I have now two views with the same base type. What is exactly the purpose of this attribute ? Am I right to think I can have as many as required view with the same basetype ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BaseViewID must be unique for each view. 1 is the ID of the AllItems view, which has no filters, that's why you can't see your filters.

Refer to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/52e45ddd-73a8-400f-890c-323a0eaaeccb

Answer (score 3):

`BaseViewID` is a confusing name. It should have been named just `ViewID` which is what it exactly is.

You BaseViewID must be unique for each view in a list. Try giving the BaseViewID as 3 to your "My Items" View.