# What tp_BaseViewID means?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, list-view, content-database

I'm little bit confused where to find a content or a row which is referenced to tp_BaseViewID column of AllWebParts table in WSS_Content databse. What this ID actually means and where to find this data ?

My goal is recreate a list view via SP client model selecting and parsing all needed data from WSS_Content databse. I usually use [tp_View] column data. But sometimes tp_View is Null and the query returns data looks like this:

```
tp_SiteId                            tp_ID                                tp_ListId                            tp_Type tp_Flags    tp_BaseViewID tp_DisplayName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  tp_Version  tp_PageUrlID                         tp_PartOrder tp_ZoneID                                                        tp_IsIncluded tp_FrameState tp_View                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          tp_WebPartTypeId                     tp_AllUsersProperties                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            tp_PerUserProperties                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             tp_Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         tp_UserID   tp_Source                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        tp_CreationTime         tp_Size              tp_Level tp_Deleted tp_HasFGP tp_ContentTypeId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   tp_PageVersion tp_SolutionId                        tp_IsCurrentVersion tp_Assembly                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     tp_Class                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        tp_WebPartIdProperty                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            tp_SolutionWebId
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------- ----------- ------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------------ ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- -------- ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
8E4B37C5-14C7-4B1B-B293-525D474F851F 2C2233B4-6C42-4CCF-8C7D-73A974C1E082 45FDCB19-4FB8-45FF-995C-92E804229ABC 1       45          3             $Resources:spscore,CategoriesList_SingleCategoryView;                                                                                                                                                                                                           1           FD0A05C0-1F50-4ACD-92D8-15C3E7E69E64 1            Main                                                             1             0             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             35AEE725-BE5B-7F5C-30F1-FB758CBC1310 NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1900-01-02 00:00:00.000 116                  1        0          0         0x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0              NULL                                 1                   NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL
8E4B37C5-14C7-4B1B-B293-525D474F851F 43DCB823-E42C-45BE-A51A-A17AD4147BB0 45FDCB19-4FB8-45FF-995C-92E804229ABC 0       37          4             $Resources:spscore,CategoriesList_CategoriesTileView;                                                                                                                                                                                                           1           3ED0A7D1-E2A8-435F-A852-CEC05ACD46EB 1            Main                                                             1             0             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             35AEE725-BE5B-7F5C-30F1-FB758CBC1310 NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL        NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1900-01-03 00:00:00.000 116                  1        0          0         0x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0              NULL                                 1                   NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NULL
```

But I always have an ID referenced to a mystery BaseView. So my question is what this tp_BaseViewID means and which data it is referenced to ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_farnhill/2013/12/04/directly-querying-sharepoint-databases/

Answer (score 1):

1st, Direclt querying the SQL server may put you out of support. read this: [Support for changes to the databases that are used by Office server products and by Windows SharePoint Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr)

[**BaseViewID = "Integer"**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms438338.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) : Specifies the ID of the base view.

BaseViewID is a confusing name. It should have been named just ViewID which is what it exactly is.

[Defining custom views in a list's schema.xml file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37480/defining-custom-views-in-a-lists-schema-xml-file)